# Regular Expression Removing All the content from File instead of matching pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, text

I have below input file:

Input File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BkRRUKn_AvtRmV4L1pQlNLIPL7pVRAoY

I'm trying to add spaces in the text file matching 2 cases as below, and keeping the rest of unmatched line as it is.

- Case 1:
  Any line starting from keyword **Product**.
- Case 2:
  Any line starting from "**14 Spaces**" followed by "**Any 4 character**" and "**End of Line**"

So that the output would be as below for a new file or new modified input file.

Output File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BkXjlrMG39yusKQ5dw8gYCGYo25xCrXF

Input:
[image: Input]

Output:
[image: Output]

What I have tried?

```
import re
import fileinput

pattern1 = re.compile('[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]+([0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z][0-9,A-Z]+)$')
pattern2 = re.compile('PRODUCT:+/^[A-Z]{0,10}$/')

for line in fileinput.input('Input_File_S.txt', inplace = True, backup='.bak'):
   if re.search(pattern1,line):
       line = re.sub(pattern1, '                                                                                                                                      \1', line)
   elif re.search(pattern2,line):
       line = re.sub(pattern2, '                                                                                                                                      \1', line)
```

However this is just removing all the content from my file. Any help on what i am doing wrong or any corrections would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `'PRODUCT:+/^[A-Z]{0,10}$/'` is an example of a corrupt regex pattern that never matches any string. A start of string position will always be false in between two consuming patterns. Do not mix regex literal notation with string patterns, Python does not support the former.

Answer (score 2):

Try pattern: `^(?:Product.+| {14}[a-zA-Z]{4}$)`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of a line

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`Product.+` - match `Product` and one or more of any characters (except new line)

`|` - alternation (or),

`{14}` - match space 14 times

`[a-zA-Z]{4}` - match lower or uppercase character 4 tiems

`$` - match end of a line

Comment: Thanks for answering and the detailed explanation which helped me to understand the working. I modified the same just to consider Numbers as well for pattern 2.   ^(?:Product.+| {14}[0-9,a-zA-Z]{4}$) Two Points:  One:using the same pattern in code still removes everything from file however when using in Notepad++ it find the pattern correctly. Two: How should I frame the replacement string to just increase the space when this pattern is matched while keeping the rest string and other non matching rows as it is

Comment: @Rahul Pay attention to flag modifiers (which make `^` and `$` behave differently).